# HTTPS Protocol Redirection Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to make all redirect_to methods' protocol HTTPS?
I know that I cant specify the protocol for a single call of redirect_to method like:

```
redirect to protocol: "https://", controller: "my_controller", action: "my_action"
```

So is there a way to make all redirect_to method calls with https protocol.

Comment: I am sure there is a rails way, but I think its common practice to establish what you wish to achieve in your webservers (e.g. nginx) configuration.

Answer (score 0):

No, as per my info.

The solution you can use is to have before_filter callbacks to take care of actions for which redirect requests will come. For urls outside the application specifically mention the absolute url with protocol.

```
https://www.securewebaccess.com
```

Add filters in controllers where you want actions to listen to https redirect calls, say for update and destroy actions in games_controller.

Place this code in application controller or somewhere generic,

```
def https_redirect
  redirect_to :protocol => "https://" unless (request.ssl? || request.local?)
end
```

Controller file:

```
class GamesController
  before_filter :https_redirect, :only => ["update","destroy"]
end
```